# Docker swarm nginx bad gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I have one docker swarm service running in my worker node, which is TOMCAT instance. The command is for running it is like below:-

```
docker service create --with-registry-auth --replicas 1 --network overlaytest --name sq-web --hostname sq-web --constraint 'node.hostname != manager' nw/sq-web:snapshot-16
```

And have one nginx container not running as swarm service but as individual container, command used like below:-

```
docker run -itd --restart=unless-stopped --name=nginx-reverse-proxy-server --network=overlaytest -p=80:80 nw/nginx:release-9
```

Both are on a same overlay network and work just fine. Command used to create the network:-

```
docker network create --driver overlay --attachable overlaytest
```

But the problem comes when I remove the the service and start it again(not updating it), then the nginx gives error - **`502 Bad Gateway`** and to recover from this I have to remove the nginx container and start again

So if there is any way for doing the remove and start of nginx image?